# Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute 'completed' in React 2020

Tags: reactjs, attributes, boolean

I have researched all solutions to this problem. The main ones being:
completed={false}
or
completed={value ? 1 : 0}
or
completed="false"

None of them seem to work.

My code todos.js:

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [
                ...state,
                    {
                    id: uuidv4(),
                    text: action.todo.text,
                    date: action.todo.date,
                    completed: false
                }
            ];

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome. [Here is the Repo Link.](https://github.com/FilipZafran/Best-TO-DO-App-in-the-history-of-the-universe)

Comment: I take you use this state somewhere in the component and that's probably where it throws this warning. Do you use PropTypes? I would check the Components that are consuming this state as this is most likely referring to them.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback.
So how do I find out where to change the code and what to change?

https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-sun-g8x09

Comment: The error gives you the exact line to look at: ```in p (at TodoList.js:58)```. Seems that you have a ```p``` tag that you set the completed prop. P does not have completed prop

Comment: ahhh, I see now... it stayed after the copy paste up. Thanks!